# Export to excel from linqDataSource in ASPX C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

How can export to excel all filtered data from a gridview witch has as datasource a linqdatasource? 
I am using aspx c#

Comment: I dont think that `SO` provides code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **EPPLUS** which provides a **FromDataTable** method.

Comment: I think EPPLUS  is not free

Comment: Look here: http://epplus.codeplex.com/
It is free and licensed under LGPL - which allows you to distribute the Library, but you have to provide the end user with documentation and the Licencse. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License